# 5 Year averages of panel variables

Tags: r

I am running a regression on a panel dataset for the years 1990-2014, such as

```
log(y_t2)=log(y_t1)+log(gfcf)+log(pg)+log(second)
```

the difference between t2 and t1 is five years and the variables gfcf, pg, secondary have been taken to be 5 year averages.

The code i use to run the regression is

```
pooling=plm(log(y)~log(lag(y,5))+log(s_k)+log(n1+5),data = Growth,index=c("country", "year"),model = "pooling")
```

the issue it seems is that there is a difference in the observation periods, how can i change this to make it such that the regression only considers values t2 and t1 for periods

```
t1=1990 t2=1994,t1=1995 t2=2000,...,t1=2010 t2=2014
```

An example would be as such:

```
Country Year GDP POP PHYS
1       1990 10  1.2 16
1       1991 11  1.1 17
...     ...  ..  ... ..
1       1994 14  1.3 19
...     ...  ... ... ...
1       2014 20  1.3 19
```

Then I took 5 year averages of Population growth and physical capital such that I have:

```
  pop  1.25 (Average for years 1990-1994)
  pop  1.5  (Average for years 1995-1999)

  Phys 1.5  (average for years 1990-1994)
```

and so on for `2000-2004,...,2010-2014` and the same for physical capital. What I am aiming to get is a regression that assesses

```
  Log(GDP(1994))=Log(GDP(1990)+Log(POP)+Log(PHYS)
```

where the pop and phys is the average for the time period for 1990-1994. I hope this clarifies a little bit.

I suppose the dataframe would look a bit like this:

```
  Country Year        GDP POP  PHYS
    1       1990-1994   4   1.25 1.5
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible toy example? And what you'd like as output?

Comment: Hi, no problem, i'll edit the post